# Hajos construction on C4

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I've been asked to prove that  χ(H(G, v1, v2)) = χ(G) where H(G,v1,v2) is the Hajós construction of G.

However, if I understand the Hajós construction as it's described on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haj%C3%B3s_construction), then H(C4,v1,v2) produces C7. This is an issue because χ(C4) = 2 and χ(C7) = 3, which would seem to disprove the conjecture.

Might I be constructing H(C4,v1,v2) incorrectly?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haj%C3%B3s_construction#Constructible_graphs

Comment: Not sure that section applies, but immediately above it is "If G and H are cycle graphs of length p and q respectively, then the result of applying the Hajós construction is itself a cycle graph, of length p + q − 1."

Comment: which conjecture you want to disprove, this one?? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadwiger_conjecture_(graph_theory)#Generalizations